# What are the implications and semantics for choosing a mode in Unison's distributed package?

Tags: distributed-computing, unison-lang

I searched through the documentation but may have missed where `unique type Mode = Parallel | Sequential` is discussed. In particular I'm trying to use it in `Seq.fromList`, which says:

```
Seq.fromList : Mode -> [a] -> Seq k a
```

...

> All branches in the result tree will have the provided `Mode`

Is this a means of controlling nested parallelism, as seems to be indicated, or is it something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that's right. Certain operations like `reduce` will examine the `Mode` and use that to decide whether to use parallelism when processing that node in the tree.

Also see [this article section discussing controlling the granularity of parallelism](https://www.unison-lang.org/articles/distributed-datasets/additional-topics/#controlling-chunking-and-the-granularity-of-parallelism)